# iOS switching between UIWebViews causing memory warning

Tags: ios, uiwebview, webview

Hi i have created a custom tab bar that hides and shows certain web views depending on which tab your on i'm currently loading all three web views on an operation queue then making them visable and invisable depending on the selected tab. problem is its so slow to load and scroll and i'm getting a recieved memory warning

heres what i have done so far

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    NSArray *subviews = [cell subviews];
        for(UIView *subview in subviews) if([subview tag] == 4) [subview removeFromSuperview];

        UIView *loadingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 800)];
        UIView *sendingMessage = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
        UIActivityIndicatorView *sendingSpinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 15, 50, 50)];
        UILabel *sendingLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 65, 100, 20)];

        int sendingViewLeft = (loadingView.frame.size.width/2) - (sendingMessage.frame.size.width/2);
        int sendingViewTop = 160 - (sendingMessage.frame.size.height/2);

        loadingView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5];

        sendingMessage.frame = CGRectMake(sendingViewLeft, sendingViewTop, sendingMessage.frame.size.width, sendingMessage.frame.size.height);
        sendingMessage.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5];
        sendingMessage.layer.cornerRadius = 10;

        sendingSpinner.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge;

        sendingLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        sendingLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        sendingLabel.text = @"Loading...";
        sendingLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        sendingLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
        sendingLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        sendingLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, -1);

        [sendingSpinner startAnimating];
        [sendingMessage addSubview:sendingLabel];
        [sendingMessage addSubview:sendingSpinner];
        [loadingView addSubview:sendingMessage];

        [loadingView setTag:4];

       cell.textLabel.text = @"";


    if([self.webViewStatus isEqualToString:@"FALSE"]){
        [cell addSubview:loadingView];
        self.tableView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    } else {
        [cell addSubview:self.fixturesWebView];
        [cell addSubview:self.resultsWebView];
        [cell addSubview:self.tablesWebView];
        self.tableView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }


    if(self.selectedTabNumber == 1){
        self.fixturesWebView.alpha = 1;
        self.resultsWebView.alpha = 0;
        self.tablesWebView.alpha = 0;
    }

    if(self.selectedTabNumber == 2){
        self.fixturesWebView.alpha = 0;
        self.resultsWebView.alpha = 1;
        self.tablesWebView.alpha = 0;
    }

    if(self.selectedTabNumber == 3){
        self.fixturesWebView.alpha = 0;
        self.resultsWebView.alpha = 0;
        self.tablesWebView.alpha = 1;

    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: And what exactly is the question here?

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should consider creating a custom cell rather than creating it at the tableview datasource. Second, when you are getting the webview content, consider using Asynchronous calls to avoid lock ups. This could be done in a block too. If you write delegate methods on the custom cell, you can let the tableview know when things are loaded or not etc.

But it looks like you are making it do too much work when the tableview needs to draw a cell.